# My throttle function is not waiting the limit time

Tags: javascript, throttling

I'm learning throttling and I'm having an issue where my throttle method is not waiting the `limit` time to run.

```
const display = (msg) => {
    console.log(msg). // I know this function does not do anything, but I'm trying to understand how I can call a function inside my throttle.
}

const throttle = (func, limit) => {
    let flag = true;
    return function() {
        if(flag) {
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            flag = false;
            setTimeout(() => flag = true, limit);
        }
    }
}

const throttleDisplay = () => {
    return throttle(display("Hi"), 6000);
}

for(let i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    setTimeout(throttleDisplay, i*1000);
}
```

My output is "Hi" 10 times, but I shouldn't have 10 times Hi because I have a 6s wait between one call and another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throttle` takes a *callback* as a parameter, but you're invoking `display` immediately.

```
const throttleDisplay = () => {
    return throttle(display("Hi"), 6000);
}
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
const throttleDisplay = () => {
    const result = display("Hi");
    return throttle(result, 6000);
}
```

See the problem?

You need a function that invokes `display` with the argument you want instead:

```
const throttleDisplay = () => {
    return throttle(() => display("Hi"), 6000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got what you said, but after changing the `throttleDisplay` to return `return throttle(() => display("Hi"), 6000);`, nothing displays in my console.log

Comment: I figured it out. It should be ```const throttleDisplay = throttle(() => display("Hi"), 6000);```